# Effect of 301 redirecting many pages from one directory/folder to another (same domain)?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, pagerank, google-ranking

I'd like to see the effects of 301 redirecting a bunch of pages from one path to another on the same domain. Example:

- From: `mysite.com/stuff/[product_id]`
- To: `mysite.com/products/[product_id]`

I would of course make sure to change the rel canonical tag as well.

Has anyone done this on a somewhat large scale?

If so, what were the results? I'd expect some level of bouncing around in the SERP, but how did it shake out? Net positive effect on your rankings? Neutral? Negative?

I'm curious to hear any war stories. I've heard from others and read in Google rater guidelines that different parts of sites can be judged independently, and I'm curious to see if the same content will rank differently given a new URL path.

Comment: It will likely shake out neutral. Short term it will very slightly reduce the ranking, but it woll bounce back.  A 301 redirect is said to transfer **most** of its juice. So the DA will be the same but the PA of the new site will be slughtly less.

Comment: DA and PA are not Google metrics, how they work is based on how the metric provider does things, not Google. A long time back Google removed the official 'juice leak' for redirects. Google may not transfer 'link juice' of it does not think the destination is about the same thing. This is more likely if bunches of URLs redirect to the same location. The URL text is a small signal. Focus on internal linking and content.

Comment: Go for it if it fits your taxonomy better not because of CEO. as stayed by @davidgo if setup will works correctly no CEO effect in long term